# Why is updated Java running old version?

Tags: windows-7, java

I have windows 7 on a 64 bit.  I'm using both a 64 bit and 32 bit browsers.

I've updated java to current version (1.6.0_35) but control panel \ java \ about says it's running outdated version 1.6.0_017.

further, the java tab in java control panel tells me i have three versions installed. 
1.7.0_07 in Program Files (x86)
1.6.0_17 in Program Files
1.6.0_35 in Program Files (x86)

how do i get the current version running?

Comment: Try in command prompt: java -version

Comment: I suspect that the old version is embedded in your Windows default PATH.

Comment: The version that is shown in the command prompt has no relation to the one that the browser users.

Comment: from the command prompt, its running java version 1.6.0_17,  java SE runtime environment 1.6.0_17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 32 bit browser will call a 32 bit JRE and your 64 bit browser will call a 64 bit JRE.

32 bit JRE are installed in `Program Files (x86)` while the 64 bit JRE is installed in `Program Files`.

In your case, it seems the most recent 64 bit JRE you have is 1.6.0_17.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect something went wrong when I updated from a non-admin account.

I uninstalled all three versions and re-installed the current 1.7 version. It's running the current version now.

Answer (score 0):

Is the old version showing up in the 32 bit or 64 bit browser? If it's on the 64 bit one, see if installing the x64 version of 1.6.0_35 fixes the browser plugin.

If this doesn't work, you can launch "Java" from the Control Panel. It will allow you to pick which JRE on your system should be used and lets you pick others manually if they weren't found.

As an aside, for the JVM/JDK used from the command line I like to have more control over what version is being used, so I have a set of system environment variables to set the JVM on the path. I have a JAVA_HOME variable that is included in my PATH set to the bin directory.
I also have a set of system environment variables for each version of JVM installed, e.g. `JAVA_HOME_1_6_17`, `JAVA_HOME_1_7_2`, `JAVA_HOME_1_6_35`, which I create when I install a new JVM that point to the installation directories of each one.
The JAVA_HOME variable just points to the JDK version I want to use, such as `JAVA_HOME=JAVA_HOME_1_6_35`

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution would be to deinstall all installed JREs and JDKs and the download the newest 32bit and 64 JRE and install them.

Those JREs will install to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7` and `C:\Program Files x86\Java\jre7`

Based on the installation pathes you also had some JDKs installed. As long as you don't develop in Java you don't need them.

Please note that JDKs are not automatically updated. You have to download a new JDK, install it and deinstall the old one.